# Map with Geo-Data-Points from Database in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, api

I have a database with various addresses and associated geo-coordinates. Do you know of any good sites that I can send this data to via an API and then embed it via an iFrame? Since it's just for a small test project, the site would have to be free. I've searched a lot but can't find anything suitable as the site either costs money or can only handle one point.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English - i come from Germany

Comment: Your solution will likely be a combination of `php` and client-side programming (`javascript`) - one such approach would be to use on the client side [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/index.html) . I'd recommend adding a `javascript` tag to get more interest (if it doesn't get closed due to asking for recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for markers placed on a map?
I am not aware of any site like that, what I would do is just implement the google maps API locally its quick and easy to do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).